# De-duplicate data in postgresql based on few columns

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have a table in psql
[image]

where column T1 represent time (t5> t4> t3> t2> t1)

I want to remove all the rows except the one with the latest time, with same value of column C1 and C2,

i.e I want

[image]

Can someone please help me with the query for this. I am new to psql so i am not able to figure out this on my own.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `distinct on`:

```
select distinct on (c1, c2) t.*
from t
order by c1, c2, t1 desc;
```

In a delete, you can use:

```
delete from t
    where t.t1 < (select max(t2.t1)
                  from t t2
                  where t2.c1 = t.c1 and t2.c2 = t.c2
                 );
```

Comment: This is a select statement, I want to delete the data.

Comment: Wouldn't `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION by c1,c2 ORDER BY t1)` be better to find and order the duplicates? It would avoid the self-join

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos . . . "better" in what way?  `distinct on` usually performs better and you cannot directly use `row_number()` in a delete.